# jQuery Save css background color in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to save a background color of an element in a variable which I sent with an AJAX call, so I can use it in a PHP SESSION, but for some reason I cannot save this css in the variable.

```
var color_rgb   = $( "#config-steps #selected-color" ).css( 'background-color' );
```

My AJAX call works fine, I have tested to put a test string in `color_rgb` and this works fine.

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: sbg.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        color_rgb: color_rgb,
        action: 'sbg_config'
    }

});
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: So your Problem is getting the background color? What is the problem exactly? Is it the worng color, is it an empty string? is your ajax call not called? Provide more Details please!

Comment: What `alert(color_rgb);` says?

Comment: @AndreschSerj empty string

Comment: Can we see your HTML? FWIW; since `selected-color` is an id, and they should be unique, there should be no need to prepend the selector with `#config-steps`

Comment: @RohanKumar it says: rgb(0,0,0,0)

Comment: @oGeez I have changed the selectors, thanks

Comment: @gbestard No this is not dublicate, I know how to get the background color of an element. Only I want to put it in a variable and send it.

Comment: @Robbert then you need to convert it in string or a `hex number`, otherwise it will look for a `rgb function`, and which is undefined

Comment: @RohanKumar Okay, but I used color_rgb: String(color_rgb), as theHarsh answered. But I still get rgba(0,0,0,0)..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    return '#' + parts.join('');
}
var color_rgb = $("#config-steps #selected-color").css( 'background-color' );
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: sbg.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        // set default black, if not color found, else convert it by hex function
        color_rgb: color_rgb ? hexc(color_rgb) : '#000000',
        action: 'sbg_config'
    }
});
```

Check the `id` of your selector. Is it exists or not.

Comment: I tried your code but my developer tool gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. I looks like I need to define colorval..?

Comment: Your last edit still gives the same error. It looks like colorval needs to be defined.

Comment: Did you add `var color_rgb = $("#config-steps #selected-color").css( 'background-color' );` before `ajax-call`

Comment: Yes I did. I don't understand why it is gonna be wrong.

Comment: Can you make an online demo for it

Comment: I can, but I also can send you the URL of the project so you can see everything?

Comment: It works see this http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/34YUs/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51743/discussion-between-robbert-and-rohan-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

Cast a variable to String in Ajax Call like this :

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: sbg.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        color_rgb: String(color_rgb),
        action: 'sbg_config'
    }
});
```